# Building a hirarchical iphone app

Tags: iphone

I have a database of tens of thousands of records which I wish to publish as an IPhone app for browsing. Are there any alternatives to using Objective C that allow me to import the records and build this type of app?

Comment: What form is the DB in now? Will the DB be local to device or will it be server based?

Comment: The data is in a database. The data is all text based, quite small records (about 100 bytes each) and the whole thing will be included in the app

Comment: There are a lot types of databases. Is an SQL db or a CVS file? Depending on the form the data is in now, different options will be easiest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the use of http://www.phonegap.com. This will allow you to bulid apps using the technology that you know and allow you to build to other platforms

Comment: +1 PhoneGap would be a good option for someone who already knows Javascript, JSON and related technologies.

Comment: @Zubair is this what you were looking for ?